# Cannot run test in chrome browser #windows7 #cypress

Tags: typescript, google-chrome, cypress

I am trying to run my tests in chrome, I have windows7..
and got message 4
"Can't run because you've entered an invalid browser name.

Browser: 'chrome' was not found on your system or is not supported by Cypress.

Cypress supports the following browsers:

- chrome
- chromium
- edge
- electron
- firefox

You can also use a custom browser: [https://on.cypress.io/customize-browsers"](https://on.cypress.io/customize-browsers%22)

in my script there is: "test:chrome": "cypress run --spec 'tests/e2e/*.spec.ts' --config baseUrl=https://www.google.com --browser chrome"

cypress version the newest one
I have run in electron but stll got some timeout ,so added to one file timeout but than test takes long...not good solution;/ I have read this problem occurs on electron

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check whether chrome installed on your machine is compatible with the cypress? You can find it simply by running `Cypress Test Runner`

[image: Cypress test runner]

If you find chrome in the dropdown, you can try to run test using this test runner.

If you still face the issue, try to update the browser.

Comment: Thanks but I can see ONLY Electron87...I have google chrome 88 on my disc, ff too...but when run test runner only electron

Comment: I found similar issues on the cypress repository. Please look at this and see if it helps https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/3645

Comment: thx i did it earlier too clearing appData , did not help:(